# More Extensive Body for Gmail Atom Feed

Tags: c#, email, gmail

I have developed a simple application for getting the atom feed of a gmail account and saving it's contents to a xml file. This application is for prototyping purposes and will be used at a later stage when i can figure it all out. Thus far everything works perfectly, however the body the atom feeder returns is just a short summary. Now i understand that the atom feeder only returns unread emails in the inbox, and the contents it returns is the subject,fromAdress,Summary and a few other logistical fields, however at no point does it return the full body, and that is what i require, how do i achive this?

Here is a copy of my code :

```
 private void btnGetFeed_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        var url = @"https://gmail.google.com/gmail/feed/atom";

        var Username = "me@email.com";
        var Password = "mycode";

        var encoded = TextToBase64(Username + ":" + Password);

        var myWebRequest = HttpWebRequest.Create(url);
        myWebRequest.Method = "POST";
        myWebRequest.ContentLength = 0;
        myWebRequest.Headers.Add("Authorization","Basic " + encoded);

        var response = myWebRequest.GetResponse();
        var stream = response.GetResponseStream();

        XmlReader reader = XmlReader.Create(stream);
        XmlDocument doc = new XmlDocument();
        doc.Load(reader);
        doc.Save("AtomFeed.xml");



    }

    public static string TextToBase64(string sAscii)
    {
        System.Text.ASCIIEncoding encoding = new System.Text.ASCIIEncoding();
        byte[] bytes = encoding.GetBytes(sAscii);
        return System.Convert.ToBase64String(bytes, 0, bytes.Length);
    }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use aenetmail's IMAP client:
[github](https://github.com/andyedinborough/aenetmail)

Here's an example:

```
using (var ic = new AE.Net.Mail.ImapClient("imap.gmail.com", "email", "pass", AE.Net.Mail.AuthMethods.Login, 993, true))
{
    ic.SelectMailbox("INBOX");
    MailMessage[] mm = ic.GetMessages(0, 10);
    // at this point you can download the messages
}
```

Comment: Thank you very much, no one else was help full on this subject.

Comment: Just a question, i went to the site and downloaded the latest version, however, what cs files should i add to my solution?

Comment: Good question. They don't provide a DLL you can just reference from your project. Instead, download the zip, extract it in its entirety, then open Visual Studio the solution where you want to use this: File -> Add existing project and browse to AE.Net.Mail.csproj.